# ¿Es incorrecto decir "3,5 años de edad"?

Tags: traducción, números

[image: Inglés: "Designed for infants only. Age up to 3.5 years and weight less than 50 lbs." Francés: "Conçu pour les enfants en bas âge seulement. Moins de 3 ans et demi et pesant moins de 22.7 kg (50 lb.)." Español: "Deseñado sólo para bebés. Hasta 3 años y 6 meses de edad y menos de 22,7 kg (50 libras) de peso."]

Vi esta letrera en un baño, con instrucciones en 3 idiomas. La edad máxima del bebé está escrita con punto decimal en inglés y como "3 ans et demi" en francés, pero en español es la forma más larga "3 años y 6 meses".

La traducción francesa tiene sentido claro, pero creía que el uso del punto o la coma decimal era más o menos universal. En español ¿es incorrecto escribir la edad con coma decimal?

//

I saw this sign in a bathroom, with instructions in 3 languages. The maximum age of the baby is written with a decimal point in English and as "3 ans et demi" in French, but in Spanish is the longer form "3 años y 6 meses".

The French translation makes clear sense, but I thought the use of the decimal point or comma was more or less universal. Is it incorrect in Spanish to write ages with a decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta Rápida: No es incorrecto.

Sin embargo, es muy probable que a muchas personas les tome por sorpresa debido a que prácticamente nunca se usa. Además, las diferencias entre el uso de la coma y el punto decimal podría hacer mas confuso el significado.

Por ejemplo, si un mexicano lee 3,5 podría no estar seguro de si se refieren a tres años y medio o tres años cinco meses.

Para el caso de México, hay tres alternativas. Se puede escribir años y meses o escribir la edad solo en meses. La especificación solo en meses es quizá mas útil hasta  36 meses (3 años). Tambien se puede usar años y medio.

En el caso específico de la pregunta, se podría decir:

- Diseñado para bebés de hasta tres años y medio...
- Diseñado para bebés de hasta tres años y seis meses...
- Diseñado para bebés de hasta cuarenta y dos meses ...

Como es más de treinta y seis meses, quizá sería forzar mucho la especificación en meses solamente. Aunque tampoco sería incorrecto.

Answer (score 2):

Seguro que de manera coloquial no es común (habitual, o entendible en la comunicacion oral) "decir"

> `3.5 años de edad`

para aludir a "tres años y medio" o a "tres años y seis meses".

Pero ese formato, por la brevedad, es muy corriente y aceptado en informes estadísticos y escritos. Como verificación véase cuantas resultados para ocasiones de uso arroja [una búsqueda en Google books de una notación del tipo](https://www.google.com/search?q=%223.5%20a%C3%B1os%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdcNDECqquyCfUESo1dNt4E2O1JSmA:1682686827068&ei=a8NLZMHiA_jS1sQP8qWj-As&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiBxOH00Mz-AhV4qZUCHfLSCL84FBDy0wN6BAgOEAk&biw=768&bih=375&dpr=3.5) (en la que además la cifra coincide exactamente)

Esto representa una constatación práctica de que en el campo editorial —fuertemente tamizado por revisores y guardianes del buen uso—, esta forma del empleo de decimales en los años es perfectamente correcta y comprensible

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

No es incorrecto decir 3,5 años, pero no es la manera más adecuada.

En trabajos o documentos referidos a estadística es más frecuente utilizar números decimales aun refiriéndose a la edad; no obstante, pienso que hablar de "3 años y medio" o "3 años y 6 meses" resulta más adecuado, sobre todo a la hora de hablar.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutamente nadie en español dice *tres años y medio* en un cartel con una alerta, solo se utiliza para describir la edad de un niño:

- Mi sobrino tiene tres años y medio
- Mi hijo tiene tres años y seis meses

En casos de advertencia por motivos x, el mensaje es

- Para menores de más de tres años
  o
- Para niños de más de tres años